# Multistore: share product/category data between storeviews

Tags: database, category, magento-1, product-attribute, multistore

I need to share some product and category data (mostly text/textarea fields) between multiple storeviews ...

- website 1

  - b2c

    - de (use default)
    - en
    - ...
  - b2b

    - en (same data as in "**b2c-en**" view)
    - ...

Everytime I update i.e. product/category attribute in "b2c-en" it should also be saved/reused in "b2b-en" storeview.

Is there a way to manipulate SQL-query that saves proudct/category data to save it for serveral storeviews? Or any other ideas?

Comment: Hi sv3n, I know about rules, But can you help regarding this.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/235256/magento-update-configurable-product-attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution w/o changing queries ...

1. add some admin config sections to ...

   - set attrributes to sync
   - map stores
2. add observers for `catalog_category_save_after` and `catalog_product_save_after`
3. compare `getData()` and `getOrigData()` for configured attributes

Sample observer code (maybe someone has better ideas):

```
# category data
$category = $observer->getCategory();
if ($syncData = /* ... */) {
    foreach ($this->getTargetStoreIds($category->getStoreId()) as $storeId) {
        $category->setStoreId($storeId);
        $category->addData($syncData);
        foreach ($syncData as $attribute => $value) {
            $category->getResource()->saveAttribute($category, $attribute);
        }
    }
}

# product data
$product = $observer->getProduct();
if ($syncData = /* ... */) {
    foreach ($this->getTargetStoreIds($product->getStoreId()) as $storeId) {
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
            array($product->getId()),
            $syncData,
            $storeId
        );
    }
}
```